# problem displaying habtm relation of a specific user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I got 3 tables (Accessories, User, Accesories_Users)... At Accessories_Controller im trying just to get the accessories from the user logged in, so i set the recursive=1 and then execute the find...

The problem is, if i do

$this->Accessory->find("All", array('conditions'=>array('AccessoriesUser.user_id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'), 'AccessoriesUser.Accesory_id'=>'Accessory.id')));

theres an error cus it doesnt find Accessory_id field.... I could manage this using a custom query but is not the idea... And then even if i do the custom query solution i cannot paginate the array that the query return...

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me...

Comment: Please add the relevant database schema and the relationships that you have defined in your models.

Comment: might want to check case on AccessoriesUser.Accesory_id

Answer (score 0):

just use var `$paginate = array('conditions'=>array())`
and for habtm relations `$this->model->bindModel('hasOne'=>aaray('otherModel'));`